# stretch image to fit without being background image (parallax)

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a 'parallax' effect. However, the only way I've seen is to use a div and set it to fixed and not repeat. The only problem is that the image has a 'border' around it, on top and the sides. I'm thinking this is because of the div, any clever solutions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Demo parallax effect</title>
<style>
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("macbook.jpeg");
  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 410px; 
/*    max-width: 100%;*/

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color: aliceblue;font-size:36px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the margin of body hope it will work please check the following code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Demo parallax effect</title>
<style>
body {
   margin: 0 !important;
} 
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("macbook.jpeg");
  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 410px; 
  /*  max-width: 100%; */

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parallax"></div>
<div style="height:1000px;background-color: aliceblue;font-size:36px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margins from the body:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Demo parallax effect</title>
  <style>
    .parallax {
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/410");
      /* Set a specific height */
      min-height: 410px;
      /*    max-width: 100%;*/
      /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parallax"></div>

  <div style="height:1000px;background-color: aliceblue;font-size:36px">
    Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect. This div is just here to enable scrolling. Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the margins from the body tag in your CSS.
Here's a working example:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.parallax {
  background-image: url("macbook.jpeg");
  min-height: 410px; 
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```